# Nginx, PHP-fpm not posting data randomly?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, nginx

i have installed Nginx and PHP-fpm and have a basic site using Codeigniter setup.

Randomly, the forms will not post any data. the $_get, $_POST values are empty.

Another case observed is that suddenly, values will override.

eg: i have a form with username and password and values entered are say abc and xyz respecitvely.

the post submitted will be similar to the following:

```
$_POST['ord'] = "ername=abc";
$_POST['password'] = "xyz";
```

the same applications works great on apache.
Any ideas?

Comment: The errorlogs are also empty

Comment: how do you post data, using curl? or ajax?

Comment: its a plain HTML form no curl or ajax

Comment: so you post data with a form ? Is there any php fatal error?

Comment: Yes. i post the data with a form.  there are no errors.

Comment: explain please what you did exactly? where is your form what are you trying to post from where to where?

Comment: Also, its works for sometimes and suddenly, stops working.